# How would I create a drupal view that pulls information from 3 different activities that are all stored on a single case?

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

I want to create a drupal view that pulls in information from different activities stored on a CiviCase and information about the case and case client.

List of fields to include would be something like this: 
Case ID
Case status
Case Client
Case Client Phone
Notes from phone call with client (from activity phone call)
Form received (from activity Approval sought)
Assignee of Approval sought activity
Teacher assigned (assignee of the class allocated activity)

Is it possible to do just from views and where would I start? Is the view based on case, contact or activity?

Comment: I'd probably approach this by using the Views Field View module which enables you to create a view and embed it in another view. In this way you can create a view to expose the Teacher assigned field, another to expose the fields from the approval sought activity, and a third to expose the phone call notes, them embed them all in a case view which shows the case id etc. In this way you can filter each embedded view to the target activity type.

Comment: I have successfully accessed 2 different activities (with different activity types) by starting your view from an activity, connecting it to the case then connecting the case to an activity